# Inertia in OrbitControls from ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using THREE.OrbitControls for rotating my objects. However I would like to add some innertia for camera rotation (if someone stops moving mouse, camera stops after a while). How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Damping / inertia is now a feature of OrbitControls in r.72. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32591676/1461008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very simple way to add inertia in OrbitControls.js:

At the end of the update function (Lines 271-272 currently) you will see the following two variables set to zero:

```
thetaDelta = 0;
phiDelta = 0;
```

Change this so that instead of immediately going to zero, they just get smaller over time:

```
thetaDelta /= 1.5;
phiDelta /= 1.5;
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

For other developers who like me landed here, as of 2019 and three.js r111, the ***OrbitControls*** now support inertia out-of-the-box, it's called damping (dont ask me why) but [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32591676/4916074) will show you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a quick and dirty approach to code in this effect -

In `OrbitControls.js`, add this function just inside the main declaration(or anywhere really) -

```
this.inertiaFunction = function()
{
    scope.rotateLeft( ( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / PIXELS_PER_ROUND * scope.userRotateSpeed )/dividingFactor);
scope.rotateUp( ( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / PIXELS_PER_ROUND * scope.userRotateSpeed )/dividingFactor);
dividingFactor+=0.5;
}
```

In the `onMouseDown(event)` function, add this at the first line -

```
 dividingFactor = 1;
```

(so that the factor gets reset every time you click)

In the `onMouseUp(event)` function, added these lines in the starting -

```
dragging2=false;
timer = setTimeout(function(){dragging=false;}, 500);
```

`dragging` and `dragging2` are two flags that we use in the requestAnimFrame function to determine if the mouse HAS been lifted and 500 milliseconds have NOT passed yet.

Add this in your main animate() or requestAnimationFrame() function -

```
if(dragging && !dragging2){ controls.inertiaFunction(); }
```

This checks that if (the mouse has been lifted) AND (500ms haven't passed yet) - 
call the inertiaFunction() of the controls object(which is an instance of `THREE.OrbitControls`)

For the case that the user clicks within 500ms of lifting the mouse, we use the `timer` object to cancel the setTimeOut.
In your onMouseDown function, add this -

```
if(dragging)
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Don't forget to declare `dragging`, `timer`, and `dragging2` and `dividingFactor` as global variables. Play with the `dividingFactor` and the 500ms in the `setTimeout()` to change the distance travelled and duration of the inertial motion.