# OrbitControls with damping

Tags: javascript, three.js, orbitcontrols

Is there a way, plugin or idea to give the THREE.js `OrbitControls` the effect of inertia when spinning?

I would like to spin a world-sphere with some damping like this:
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Polyhedra.html

The original `OrbitControls` behaviour looks like this:
http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit

Comment: Damping is not a feature of `OrbitControls` in r.71. You can use `TrackballControls` if you want.

Comment: The damping feature has now been added in the r.72dev branch of three.js: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7016.

Comment: Great! You (and Mr.Doob & all the other people working on three.js) are awesome. Thanks for this information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OrbitControls now supports damping / inertia.

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;
```

Then in your animation loop add

```
controls.update(); // required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true
```

three.js r.108

Comment: this is a veeery basic implementation of inertia. the lower the damping factor, the higher is the rotation sensitivity. (more rotation per pixel dragged) Is there a chance to separate those?

Comment: @ManuelGraf `OrbitControls` is an example; it is not part of the core library. You are free to edit it as you wish, or better yet, propose a specific improvement.